# память в куче C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. Насколько я знаю ОС сама выделяет память под кучу, но как тогда работать с памятью если мы незнаем сколько ее в куче?

Comment: можно спросить у ОС, сколько ее у нас есть.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен. Что именно вы хотите узнать? Память под кучу выделяется и освобождается по мере необходимости. Выделяйте и работайте на здоровье.

Comment: Сколько изначально доступно памяти? И возможно ли узнатьэто с помощью каких-либо функций?

Comment: А какое это имеет значение, сколько ее в начале. если окажется мало того, что выдали изначально функции malloc сами позаботятся о том, что бы запросить дополнительно у ОС и так до тех пор пока не кончится вся оперативная память в системе, включая место в своп-файле

Comment: Сама ОС ничего не выделяет. Ее приходится усиленно пинать. Но в с++ этим занимается за вас аллокатор памяти, который вызывается операторами `new` / `delete`. Если памяти не будет хватать, то он проинформирует вас об этом кинув исключение `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :D